# How should text selection function for a clickable element in a web app?

Tags: html, css, web-applications, web

We are building a web app that allows elements to be expanded/collapsed.

One of the clickable items is shown below:

[image]

Notice the text selection when clicking on the element is annoying. What is the recommended approach for handling this?

Comment: That should only happen on a double-click, not a single click.

Comment: Thanks for the reply BoltClock. It does on double clicking but because the items can expand and collapse, the chances of a double click is pretty high (in my opinion)

Comment: If the user thinks that selecting text is annoying then the user shouldn't select text.  I don't see why this would be the application's concern.  You could try some JavaScript which moves focus around for various click events, but I imagine that would be a _lot_ more annoying (both for the users and the developers).

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/826782/1577396. Is this what you want?

Comment: I think the consensus is this is a bad idea, I thought it was

Comment: Do you want to disable text selection?

Comment: @ntvf I am not sure, the visual effect looks crap but the alternative of switching of text selection is worse

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox and Chrome/Safari you can use the user select property.
It is still experimental I think so you should use vendor prefixes like this:
 `#element-id{-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none;}`

As for Opera and IE I have no idea (maybe for Opera using  -o-user-select will work, but I am not sure)

EDIT: I looked around a bit, because I was also interested in this question and apparently, for Opera and IE there is an `unselectable` property. [More details about it](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwdpnva.php)

Answer (score 1):

To disable selection in a CSS way:

```
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

or you may use element attribute unselectable

```
<div unselectable="on">...</div>
```